# Compare two datatables while taking sorting into account

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datatable

I have two data tables as below and I am using the below to compare the two:

```
var diffResult = actual.AsEnumerable().Except(expected.AsEnumerable(), 
DataRowComparer.Default);

Assert.IsFalse(diffResult.Any());
```

In this scenario `diffResult` does not return anything, and works fine when I want to make sure the two tables match. However this way of comparing does not take the sorting into account.

How can I compare the two tables and return True if the two tables contain the same data and they are both ordered the same way?

```
actual
-------------------------
 Code  |   Name 
--------------------------
 101  |  A
 101  |  B
 101  |  C
--------------------------

expected
-------------------------
 Code|   Name 
--------------------------
 101  |  C
 101  |  B
 101  |  A
--------------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure? You use `Assert.IsFalse`, it would return `false` and that means the `diffResult` would have some row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx).

```
bool seqEqual = actual.AsEnumerable()
               .SequenceEqual(expected.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
```

`SequenceEqual` is only true when both lists have the same number of elements in exact the same order as defined by the comparer.